# why we are using -1 in the following code?

Tags: java, fileinputstream

Please explain why we are using -1 inside while loop

```
<%  
    File file = new File(file1);       
    int ch;       
    strContent = new StringBuffer("");       
    FileInputStream fin = null;       
    try {       
        fin = new FileInputStream(file);       
        while ((ch = fin.read()) != -1) 
            strContent.append((char) ch);
        fin.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }   
    System.out.println(strContent.toString());

%>
```

In the above code explain why we are using -1,i don't understand why we are using the -1

Comment: The statement inside the while condition should return 0 or above if it returns below 0 that might be an error while reading the file. For the reason we have added !=1

Answer (score 2):

Documentation of `read`:

> **Returns:** the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or -1 if there is no more data because the end of the file has been reached.

So, the loop ends when there is nothing more to read

Answer (score 1):

You should [read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28%29) the doc :

> the method `read()` returns -1 if the end of the file is reached.

So you want to stop your while loop when you reach the end of your file.

Answer (score 0):

This condition checks for EOF (End Of File). That is stop reading once, End of file is reached.

Answer (score 0):

This is detailed in the Java docs:

> Returns:
>   the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or -1 if there is no more data because the end of the stream has been reached.

Read more here:

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int read()
         throws IOException
```

> Reads a byte of data from this input stream. This method blocks if no
>   input is yet available.

**Specified by:**

```
read in class InputStream
```

**Returns:**

> the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the file is reached.

**Throws:**

```
IOException - if an I/O error occurs.
```